# WSO2 IS returns CORS error when wrong credentials sent

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to fetch the WSO2-IS response when user enters wrong credentials from frontend. If I hit the same end point via postman then it returns a proper response shown as follows:

```
{
    "error_description": "Client Authentication failed.",
    "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

But when request is fired from the browser it throws CORS error saying:

> request header field access-control-allow-credentials is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Although it works fine with correct user credentials.

Now since the request for authentication goes directly from client to WSO2 server I believe that no fixes are required in the backend. But I couldn't find a way to handle the same in frontend. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

The CORS error is occurring probably because you are running your frontend application on a separate host. If you are running WSO2 Identity Server 5.9.0 or later please try adding the following filter in your repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/tomcat/web.xml.j2 file to allow CORS. If you are using an older version you can add the following filter in repository/conf/tomcat/web.xml file.

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
            <param-value>{ origin of your application }</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```