# How to perform following changes in tomcat configuration in WSO2IS 5.9.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to make /oauth2/token API call from reactjs fronted and getting CORS error.

My friend asked the same question and got answer for the same also.
Please open the link for solution.

[WSO2 IS returns CORS error when wrong credentials sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058617/wso2-is-returns-cors-error-when-wrong-credentials-sent)

But when I am trying to perform the same in WSO2IS 5.9.0 the configuration is getting overwritten to the default config.
How to perform this in 5.9.0 using deployment.toml file?

Comment: Can you mention the file and the configuration you are trying to add?

Comment: As asked on that answer, you need to update `web.xml.j2`. That won't get replaced.

Comment: I want to change configuration of tomcat server and add the filters for CORS in web.xml file

Comment: I am not sure about web.xml or web.xml.j2 when i opened up the folder i was able to only see web.xml and there was no file as web.xml.j2..............is it a problem?

Comment: Please help to resolve the problem guys........

Comment: web.xml.j2 is in repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/tomcat directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in that earlier answer you need to add the given tomcat filter in the web.xml.j2 file in the path repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/tomcat. The .j2 files will not get replaced by the deployment.toml at the server startup.

Comment: Thanks mam and i have added * in origin of the application but still there is no changes. Can you plesae help regarding the same?

Comment: Instead of allowing all the origins can you specify your application's origin and see. To read further about CORS filter you may refer to [CORS Filter and HttpServletRequest attributes](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter_and_HttpServletRequest_attributes)